# vector as input to pthread_create

Tags: c++, vector, pthreads

I passed a structure into pthread_create. One component of the structure is a vector data. the "data" push_back in a loop in each thread. When the size of the loop is small, the code runs correctly. When the loop is large. I got the following error message:

munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)

I tried m<100, it works. When trying the m<1000, it shows the error.

```
// compile using: g++ parallel_2.C -o oo -lpthread
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>


using namespace std;

const unsigned NUM_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();


//
struct INPUT
{
    int start;
    int end;
    vector<int> data;
};

//
void *Loop(void *param)
{
   INPUT *in = (INPUT*)param;
   int start = in->start;
   int end = in->end;

   cout<<" start: "<<start<<" end: "<<end<<endl;
   //for(int m=0; m<100000000; m++) 
   for(int i = start;i < end;i++)
       for(int m=0; m<1000; m++) {
           in->data.push_back(i);
       }

   //pthread_exit(NULL);
}

//
int main ()
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

   INPUT input[NUM_THREADS];

   for( int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;

      input[i].start = i*5;
      input[i].end = input[i].start + 5;
      int rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL,
                          Loop, (void *)&input[i]);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }

   }
   for(int i = 0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++)
       cout<<"!! size of "<<i<<": "<<input[0].data.size()<<endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 3):

In the specific case of this example (`main()` assumes that the threads are done and consults the modified structures), you have to `join()` a thread before accessing the structure it is modifying.

```
for(int i = 0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++)
{
  pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  cout<<"!! size of "<<i<<": "<<input[0].data.size()<<endl;
}
```

This way, you are certain it is done, and not modifying the structure any more.

The problem did not show up with very few iterations because the threads had probably (but nothing is certain) ended their task before your last loop in `main()` tried to access their structures.

By the way, you should consider using `std::thread`.
(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

Comment: wow. that solved the problem. Can you be more specific on why using std::thread instead of pthread?  Any example on that? Thanks!

Comment: You are already using modern C++ with `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` so why not keep consistent? And it's within the modern C++ standard so portable.

Comment: sorry for the newbie question. Is it as simple as replacing pthread by std::thread?

Comment: @David Just added a link to the documentation (with some examples) in the answer.

Comment: @David You may find `std::future` an interesting alternative. [It describes an asynchronous operation a bit better than a thread.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)

Comment: @user4581301 You are perfectly right about the first sentence, thanks for pointing out. Do you find it better now? (fell free to edit)

Comment: I'm down with that.

Comment: @David Not at all, it has exactly the same performance, but it's type-safe (no `void *`).

Comment: @David and you can easily pass in far more complicated functions than suckers that accept a single `void*` parameter.